# Building roads on steep slopes with QGIS

Tags: qgis, slope, road

I work in forestry and want to get QGIS to generate a vector line that doesn´t exceed a certain road slope. I can get it to tell me what the slope is on a road I draw myself, but how can I just insert where I would like the road to start and end with a max slope, and have it generate the shortest way from A to B. Any ideas?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

This workflow will create a least cost line between two points, avoiding slopes above a threshold value of your choice:

1. Reclassify (**Reclassify by table**) the slope raster so values below for example 15 get a low value like 1, and values above 15 get a high value like 100. The greater difference between low and high the more it will avoid high slope in favour of longer road.
2. **r.cost** with the start point as start point. The output will be a raster with higher values the more distance/cost away from the start. Adjust "Max cumulative cost" to create a cost raster covering a large enough area.
3. **r.drain** with end points as "starting point". The tool will find the lowest cost path from start to end.
4. Convert the raster output line to vector with **r.to.vect**

You can perform each step manually or with a model:

[image]